# IIS 6 and IIS 7 in same server

Tags: iis-7, iis-6

Will there be a problem when both iis 6 and iis 7 exists in the same server? not using virtual machine

Comment: I do not agree with the off-topic votes. When you develop ASP.NET websites, it can be *very* helpful to have a basic knowledge of IIS.

Comment: If your question is answered, could you mark it as answered?

Answer (score 1):

The version of IIS is tied to the Windows Server version:

- Windows Server 2003   -> IIS6
- Windows Server 2008   -> IIS7
- Windows Server 2008R2 -> IIS7.5

So what you're asking is impossible (you can not download and install IIS, it's already part of the OS). What is possible, is that you use another type of application pool in IIS7 or IIS7.5, mimicking the behavior of IIS6. You can vary the following parameters per application pool (among many others):

- .NET Framework Version (4.0 or 2.0)
- Managed Pipeline Mode (Integrated or Classic)

With classic mode, you are effectively using the IIS6 pipeline.